# How to change OpenLayers Map styles with bright.json

Tags: openlayers, mapping

I got problem with using [Bright.json](https://github.com/openlayers/workshop/blob/master/src/en/data/bright.json) I caant load that styles to map.
So far I got

```
let vLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: new ol.source.Vector({
      url: "/www/bright.json",
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
    })
  })

  let map = new ol.Map({
    target: "map",
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      }), vLayer
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([14.437800, 50.075539]),
      zoom: 12
    })
  });
```

Comment: bright.json is a mapbox style sheet.  In OpenLayers it must be used in conjugation with the ol-mapbox-style library.  See the code example in https://github.com/openlayers/workshop/tree/master/src/en/examples/vectortile

Comment: Maptiler also has examples of using the bright style in OpenLayers, but you need to create an free account to access them https://cloud.maptiler.com/maps/bright/

Comment: @Mike OK. I understand, but on https://openmaptiles.org/, is written that OSM Bright is free.

Comment: It is free but you need a Maptiler API key to access it.

Comment: OK. Thnaks a lot. :) Add something under my topic, for points. Cya